# Regular expression negates the expression

Tags: regex

im using pcre RegExp engine , and i have string that looks like this :

```
<h3 class="description">Description</h3>   <div class="wrapper">  dddsome string blah blahddssssseeeee <div class="empty"> </div></div> </div>          </div>
```

and regexp that works fine and cpture the string "dddsome string blah blahddssssseeeee"
that looks like this :

```
<\s*h3\s*class="*.+?"\s*>.*?</\s*h3>.+?<\s*div.+?class\s*="wrapper"\s*>(.+?)<\s*div\s*class="empty">
```

now some time i have the Almost the the same pattern of string that looks like this not the div class="aplus" tag , when this tag appear i want the regexp above to fail to match the all string .

```
<h3 class="description">Description</h3>   <div class="wrapper">  <div class="aplus">  dddsome string blah blahddssssseeeee <div class="empty"> </div></div> </div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to parse HTML or XML with regular expressions, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Parsing HTML with REs? When will they ever learn?

Comment: In what language/platform are you using this regex?

Comment: i know i know , but its something that i have , and have to be parsed with regexp , so im stack with it , and still need to parse it right 
thanks, using c++ / windows / pcer regexp engine

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div.*>(.*)<div.*>
```

but use beautiful-soup for easy better web scraping